# Question about WPF Resources/Styles & Scope

Tags: wpf

i am just beginning WPF and wonder why this works

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="buttonStyle">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Button.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="Aqua" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button ... Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

but this fails,

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="buttonStyle">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Button.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="Aqua" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel ...>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style x:Name="buttonStyle2">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button ... Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
            <Button ... Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the error is

- The resource "buttonStyle2" could not be resolved
- The resource "buttonStyle" could not be resolved

`buttonStyle` resolves ok in the 1st code (without the 2nd button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arr... my bad, i should be using `x:Key` not `x:Name`